# My GridView does not add another row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView wherein i want to have data there and then will add all data into the database.

[Gridview is before my SAVE Products BTN; textboxes are before ADD Product BTN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R82Ak.png)

IT DOES ADD LIKE THIS:

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaT5A.png)

But the thing is it won't add another row....

here is my ASP.NET codes:

```
    <table >  

<tr>  

    <td class="style2">  
        Product Name  
    </td>  
    <td class="style1">  
        Price  
    </td>  
    <td>  
        Quantity  
    </td>  
    <td>  
        Amount 
    </td>  
</tr>  
<tr>  

 <td class="style2">   

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Products" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyOwnMeatshopConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [Name] FROM [Products]" ></asp:SqlDataSource>

 </td> 
  <asp:DropDownList ID="Name" runat="server" type="Number" DataSourceID="Products" 
        DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name" Width="83px" ></asp:DropDownList>   

  </td>  
 <td class="style1">   
 <asp:TextBox ID="Price" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  
 </td>  
  <td>  
  <asp:TextBox ID="Quantity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  
  </td>  
   <td>  
   <asp:TextBox ID="Amount" runat="server"></asp:TextBox    >  


   </td>  
</tr>  
<tr>  
<td class="style3"></td>  
<td class="style2"></td>   
<td>   

</td>  
<td>   
    <asp:Button ID="AddProduct" runat="server" Text="Add Product"   
        BackColor="#999966" onclick="AddProduct_Click" /></td>  
</tr>
```

```
         <asp:BoundField DataField="PurchaseNo" HeaderText="POID" 
             SortExpression="POID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="ProductID" 
             SortExpression="ProductID" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" 
             SortExpression="Name" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" SortExpression="Price" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" 
             SortExpression="Quantity" />

     </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>

    <asp:Button ID="btnsubmitProducts" runat="server" style="color:White"   
        Text="Save Products" BackColor="#999966" 
        onclick="btnsubmitProducts_Click" /> 

 <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server">
 </asp:GridView>
```

Here is my CODE BEHIND

```
public partial class PODetails : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Helper.GetCon());

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            AddProducts();

        }
    }

    void AddProducts()
    {
        ////con.Open();
        ////SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        //cmd.Connection = con;
        //creating DataTable  
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr;
        dt.TableName = "PurchaseDetails";
        //creating columns for DataTable  
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PurchaseNo", typeof(int)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ProductID", typeof(int)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Quantity", typeof(int)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Price", typeof(decimal)));
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        ViewState["PurchaseDetails"] = dt;
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();  
    }


    void AddNewRecordRowToGrid()
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        if (ViewState["PurchaseDetails"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["PurchaseDetails"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;

            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {

                    //Creating new row and assigning values  
                    drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
                    drCurrentRow["Name"] = Name.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["Quantity"] = Convert.ToInt32(Quantity.Text);
                    drCurrentRow["Price"] = Convert.ToDecimal(Price.Text);
                    //drCurrentRow["Price"] = Convert.ToDecimal(Price.Text);

                }
                //Removing initial blank row  
                if (dtCurrentTable.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "")
                {
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[0].Delete();
                    dtCurrentTable.AcceptChanges();

                }

                //Added New Record to the DataTable  
                dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                //storing DataTable to ViewState  
                ViewState["PurchaseDetails"] = dtCurrentTable;
                //binding Gridview with New Row  
                GridView1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }

    void BulkInsertToDataBase()
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        DataTable dtPurchaseDetails = (DataTable)ViewState["PurchaseDetails"];
        //creating object of SqlBulkCopy  
        SqlBulkCopy objbulk = new SqlBulkCopy(con);
        //assigning Destination table name  
        objbulk.DestinationTableName = "PurchaseDetails";
        //Mapping Table column  
        objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");
        objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Quantity", "Quantity");
        objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Price", "Price");
        //inserting bulk Records into DataBase   
        objbulk.WriteToServer(dtPurchaseDetails);
    }



    protected void AddProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewRecordRowToGrid();
    }

    protected void btnsubmitProducts_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BulkInsertToDataBase();
    }
```

I Just tried doing the code for adding a new row. it Just didn't work

I don't know what is wrong with my codes. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside for loop i have made some changes..try that

```
 void AddNewRecordRowToGrid()
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    if (ViewState["PurchaseDetails"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["PurchaseDetails"];
        DataRow drCurrentRow = null;

        if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
        {

            for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                //Creating new row and assigning values  
                drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Name"] = Name.Text;
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Quantity"] = Convert.ToInt32(Quantity.Text);
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Price"] = Convert.ToDecimal(Price.Text);
                //drCurrentRow["Price"] = Convert.ToDecimal(Price.Text);

            }
            //Removing initial blank row  
            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "")
            {
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[0].Delete();
                dtCurrentTable.AcceptChanges();

            }

            //Added New Record to the DataTable  
            dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
            //storing DataTable to ViewState  
            ViewState["PurchaseDetails"] = dtCurrentTable;
            //binding Gridview with New Row  
            GridView1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

If it does not work let me know. Thank You.

Comment: Hi sorry got to reply late. It works

But

Whenever i insert another data, all data is being replaced by the new data. Please Help

Comment: do you know how i can avoid to replace data inserted by another data that i will insert? @Nagib Mahfuz

Comment: you are deleting 1st row every time while adding a new row. Remove these code `if (dtCurrentTable.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "")
                {
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[0].Delete();
                    dtCurrentTable.AcceptChanges();

                }`

Answer (score 0):

you removed ! sign from ispostback in Page_Load method

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code to:

```
<table >  

<tr>  

    <td class="style2">  
        Product Name  
    </td>  
    <td class="style1">  
        Price  
    </td>  
    <td>  
        Quantity  
    </td>  
    <td>  
        Amount 
    </td>  
</tr>  
<tr>  

 <td class="style2">   

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Products" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyOwnMeatshopConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [Name] FROM [Products]" ></asp:SqlDataSource>

 </td> 
  <asp:DropDownList ID="Name" runat="server" type="Number" DataSourceID="Products" 
        DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name" Width="83px" ></asp:DropDownList>   

  </td>  
 <td class="style1">   
 <asp:TextBox ID="Price" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  
 </td>  
  <td>  
  <asp:TextBox ID="Quantity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  
  </td>  
   <td>  
   <asp:TextBox ID="Amount" runat="server"></asp:TextBox    >  


   </td>  
</tr>  
<tr>  
<td class="style3"></td>  
<td class="style2"></td>   
<td>   

</td>  
<td>   
    <asp:Button ID="AddProduct" runat="server" Text="Add Product"   
        BackColor="#999966" onclick="AddProduct_Click" /></td>  
</tr> 
</table>

 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
<Columns>
 <asp:BoundField DataField="PurchaseNo" HeaderText="POID" 
             SortExpression="POID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="ProductID" 
             SortExpression="ProductID" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" 
             SortExpression="Name" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" SortExpression="Price" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" 
             SortExpression="Quantity" />

     </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

and your code behind:

```
 public partial class PODetails : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Helper.GetCon());

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            AddProducts();

        }
    }

    void AddProducts()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.TableName = "PurchaseDetails";
        //creating columns for DataTable  
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PurchaseNo", typeof(int)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ProductID", typeof(int)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Quantity", typeof(int)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Price", typeof(decimal)));

        ViewState["PurchaseDetails"] = dt;
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }


    void AddNewRecordRowToGrid()
    {
        if (ViewState["PurchaseDetails"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["PurchaseDetails"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
            drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
            drCurrentRow["Name"] = Name.Text;
            drCurrentRow["Quantity"] = Convert.ToInt32(Quantity.Text);
            drCurrentRow["Price"] = Convert.ToDecimal(Price.Text);
            dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
            ViewState["PurchaseDetails"] = dtCurrentTable;
            GridView1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
    void BulkInsertToDataBase()
    {
    }
    protected void AddProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewRecordRowToGrid();
    }
    protected void btnsubmitProducts_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BulkInsertToDataBase();
    }
}
```